# Is it possible to quantify to what degree human experience is subjective?

Tags: subjectivity, objectivity

On the most basic level, it is true that the world subjective in the sense that there is no absolute frame that an individual can switch over to and view the world from. However, it can also be observed in day to day life that the world has a degree of objectivity to it. For example, suppose there is a beautiful classical music that of Beethoven, then there are many people in the world who would agree that the music sounds good. While the true reasons of agreement may differ, the ultimate answer to the statement "Does it sound good or not?" boils down to good in the group I am considering.

This makes me believe that instead of the world being either entirely subjective or entirely objective, it is somewhere in between. However, I am not sure how one quantify this in betweenness. Has this problem been discussed by philosophers before? What were the conclusions?

Comment: See Leibniz's Monadology where he provided a schematic framework to assign more subjectivity to soul monad, and whole objectivity to bare monad of materials, and other types in between such as plants, animals, etc...